# Extract is slower than fancy index in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

`Ndarray` has a member function `extract` to extract elements of an array that satisfy some condition. However, this function is slower than fancy index. Why should we use this function?

```
from numpy import *
a=random.random((1000,2000))
b=a>0.2
%timeit extract(b,a)
%timeit a[b]
%timeit extract(a>0.2,a)
%timeit a[a>0.2]
```

Here is my outputs:

```
In [138]: %timeit extract(b,a)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.6 ms per loop

In [139]: %timeit a[b]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop

In [140]: %timeit extract(a>0.2,a)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.4 ms per loop

In [141]: %timeit a[a>0.2]
10 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Which numpy version do you use? The numpy 1.8 extract docs say: "If `condition` is boolean `np.extract` is equivalent to `arr[condition]`".

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke There is a long standing timing discrepancy between `np.take` and fancy indexing even though these two operations are equivalent- it is not impossible that the timings vary due to various reasons. `extract` is also based off 'take' as well.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke My numpy version is 1.8.0.

Comment: So we are saying that these differences are insignificant and due to inaccurate measurement? Or in other words: this is not the right benchmark?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke According to the docs `extract` is equivalent to `np.compress(ravel(condition), ravel(arr))`, and they cost the same amount of time.

Comment: Does extract return a view or a copy?

Comment: So the answer to "Why should we use this function?" would be whenever `np.compress(ravel(condition), ravel(arr))` can do something that boolean indexing can't. So just go ahead and directly use boolean indexing whenever you can.

Comment: @M4rtini I think both of them return a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we examine `np.extract` we find the following:

```
take(a.ravel(), nonzero(ravel(b))[0])
```

What is interesting here is we take `b` which is a boolean array and convert it into indices so that the normal `np.take` operation can work as advertised. If we examine how long this takes we realize `nonzero` is the majority of the total time and fancy indexing takes less then `nonzero`:

```
%timeit nonzero(ravel(b))[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop

%timeit take(a.ravel(), nonzero(ravel(b))[0])
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop

%timeit a[b]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop
```

The [docs](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7b2f20b406d27364c812f7a81a9c901afbd3600c/doc/source/reference/internals.code-explanations.rst) explains that even fancy indexing creates an array of indices using some sort of `nonzero` like operation; however, fancy indexing does not involve a python abstraction layer. I believe the python abstraction layer is the key here. What exactly is going I would not care to speculate, but I expect there is a great deal of optimization that happens when the function is purely in the C side (as with all fancy indexing).

Comment: Ah, those docs are outdated in most regards about indexing. There is a specialized boolean indexing path when the shapes match exactly. And extract could probably be rewritten to use it (though for non-boolean arrays the nonzero logic may be better).

Comment: @seberg Good to know, would you mind pointing out the location of fancy indexing in the source code?

Comment: recently got all different (not the boolean case). Advanced indexing starts here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L1505 the simple boolean one is handled earlier though (also the nonzero calls for non-simple, it is in the prepare_index function). It isn't a walk in the park to understand how fancy indexing works, but feel free to ask me if you want help.